# Using python to create a .mat file with a cell array in it

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, cell-array

I'm trying to create a mat file with a cell it it. I tried to apply some solutions I found on the internet but non of them worked.

The code I'm wishing to have at the end is something like that:

```py
import scipy.io as sio

l = [ [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ], [ [10, 20, 30] , [40, 50, 60] ] ]

c = # Some code to make it appear as a cell array in matlab

sio.savemat('f.mat', { cell : c })
```

so the cell array at the end would look like:
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ] [ [10, 20, 30] , [40, 50, 60] ]

Comment: I'd suggest creating a sample cell and or matrix in MATLAB, save it, and the look at what `loadmat` produces.  `numpy` numeric dtype arrays transfer as `matrix`, though possibly with a change in `order`.  I think cell are rendered as object dtype array in `numpy`.  But experiment.

Comment: I tested it and you are right, np array that it's dtype is object creates a matlab cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To create a cell in a .mat file, the corresponding array in python should be a np.arrat whose dtype is np.object.

should look something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
c = np.array( array, dtype=np.object)
sio.savemat('file.mat', '{'cell' : c})
```

credit to @hpaulj that [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582920/using-python-to-create-a-mat-file-with-a-cell-array-in-it#comment124776837_70582920) this suggestion here, I checked it and it seems to work.

Comment: what is np in your code ? A missing import ?

Comment: @pippo1980
yes, np is a common short for numpy.  added the import to the code.